# Measure to find best distribution with respect to a fixed point

Tags: distribution, similarity

I have two vectors with the predicted values by 10 persons.

A = [11 29 45 36 5 67 89 44 27 98]

B = [1 15 18 19 16 45 46 24 25 21]

The actual value is C = 20

It is obvious that the distribution of predicted value in A is worse than B, when compared with teh actual value i.e. C. I have used a few similarity measures and shown that B is more similar/close to C. But I need to know if there is any probability formula or something which depicts the **distribution of a set of values (say A or B) with respect a fixed value (C)** .. remember this fixed value may or may not exist in A or B.

Thanks.

Comment: You've given a "for instance" case of C=20, but is C a known quantity in general?

Comment: Yes it is a known quantity in general.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using average quadratic loss as a measure:

> L = (1/n)Σ(x<sub>i</sub> - τ)<sup>2</sup>,

where the x<sub>i</sub>'s are individual observations from a given population (A or B), n is the size of the population, and τ is the "target value," in your case C.  This penalizes observations that are far away from the target more than those which are close.  Calculate L for each vector, and the one with the smaller average loss is better by this criterion.

A nice feature of loss is that under expectation it can be decomposed into

> E[L] = (μ - τ)<sup>2</sup> + σ<sup>2</sup>,

which means it can be estimated as

> (x-bar - τ)<sup>2</sup> + s<sup>2</sup>,

where x-bar is the sample average and s<sup>2</sup> is the classical unbiased variance estimator.  From this you can see that a low-loss vector is one that is consistently (low variance) ***and*** close to the target.  Being off on either or both of these criteria will increase the loss function.

This approach also allows you to treat τ as a parameter, so you can do "what-if" comparisons.  Since the average and sample variance of a vector don't change, assessing different τ values in the estimation formula requires O(1) work rather than O(n) work. However, note that this applies a non-linear transform to the estimated values and s<sup>2</sup> is usually calculated with (n-1) as the divisor rather than n, so this form of the estimator can be biased. It yields numerical results that are consistent with but slightly different from those of the direct calculation.  That said, it's much more convenient.

If this bothers you, using the MLE estimator for variance corrects for the bias due to squaring the sample mean.  The resulting unbiased estimator is:

> (x-bar - τ)<sup>2</sup> + (n-1)s<sup>2</sup>/n,

if s<sup>2</sup> is the commonly used unbiased estimator of variance.

For your data, I calculate L(A) = (45.1 - 20)<sup>2</sup> + 9 * 960.77 / 10 = 1494.7, which is much larger than L(B) = (23.0 - 20)<sup>2</sup> + 9 * 184.44 / 10 = 175.0.  Population B is preferred as having lower loss relative to a target of 20.  If the target is 50, then A and B have losses of 888.7 and 895.0, respectively, and A would be (just barely) preferred.